# Counting Unique Values from multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of sales quotes with id, date and status (won, lost, open).

```
Quotes = pd.DataFrame({
        'Quote_ID': [1105, 1106, 1107, 1108, 1109, 1110, 1111, 1112],
        'Quote_Date': ['2018-11-15', '2018-11-15', '2018-11-15', '2018-11-15', 
                   '2018-11-15', '2018-11-16', '2018-11-16', '2018-11-16'],
        'Status': ['won', 'open', 'won', 'lost', 'won', 'lost', 'lost', 'won']
        })

print(Quotes)

   Quote_ID  Quote_Date Status
0      1105  2018-11-15    won
1      1106  2018-11-15   open
2      1107  2018-11-15    won
3      1108  2018-11-15   lost
4      1109  2018-11-15    won
5      1110  2018-11-16   lost
6      1111  2018-11-16   lost
7      1112  2018-11-16    won
```

I would like a new dataframe that counts quotes per day and number of quotes won per day:

```
         Date  Quotes  Won
0  2018-11-15       5    3
1  2018-11-16       3    1
```

I can count the number of quotes per day using:

```
Quotes_Per_Day = Quotes['Quote_Date'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

But I am not sure how to count the number of 'won' for that given day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Boolean Series, then sum it in a `groupby`

```
(Quotes.assign(Won = Quotes.Status.eq('won'))
     .groupby("Quote_Date").agg({'Won': 'sum', 'Quote_ID': 'nunique'})
     .rename(columns={'Quote_ID': 'Quotes'}))

            Won  Quotes
Quote_Date             
2018-11-15  3.0       5
2018-11-16  1.0       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Or also:

```
Quotes.groupby('Quote_Date').agg({'Quote_ID':'count','Status':lambda x: x.eq('won').sum()}).\
  rename(columns={'Quote_ID':'Quotes','Status':'Won'})


            Quotes  Won
Quote_Date             
2018-11-15       5    3
2018-11-16       3    1
```